# HTML <a> link tag different styles speed

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

Let's say i have a certain file file.php
What i want to know is : is there any loading speed between the following or is it the same :

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/file.php">File</a> 
<a href="./file.php">File</a> 
<a href="file.php">File</a> 
<a href="/file">File</a> <!--rewrite rule-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some URLs have (obviously) more bytes than others, so it will take longer to send them over the network in the first place. This will not be a significant difference.

Browsers will resolve URLs at the same speed.

Rewrite rules require extra processing, so requests involving them will take longer. Again, this will not be a significant difference.

---

You appear to be embarking down a road of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Don't do that.

Comment: As you said (obviously), i know that the difference between the above links is hardly noticeable, what if i have 10k (i mean it) links in one page ?

Comment: Still unlikely to be significant. (At least if you do sensible performance related things such as using gzip).